# Understanding why callback functions in JavaScript are only executed when everything finishes

Tags: javascript, callback

First of all this is what understand about arguments of a method:

```
get(arg1, arg2) {
  arg1 + arg2
  //same as arg2 + arg1
}
```

As I understand it doesn't matter which argument go first the result will be the same.

So in this example:

```
 get(arg1, function(value) {
   console.log(value)
 });
```

I don't quite understand the reason the second argument (an anonymous function) its executed when all finishes. I don't even understand why it even executes if it is an argument (I understand that arguments are just variables inside a function).

For this reason I still can't understand JavaScript callbacks (I believe I'm confusing some concept).

Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A callback is simply a piece of code (a function) that you can hand around like regular values. Think of it as one more type: numbers, strings, booleans, functions. When you hand a function over as argument, the receiver can do with it what it likes and execute it when it likes.

```
function receiver(callback) {
    callback();
}

receiver(function () {
    alert('Foo');
});

var bar = function () {
    alert('bar');
};

receiver(bar);

function baz() {
    alert('baz');
}

receiver(baz);
```

The above `bar` example illustrates that functions can be handled just like regular values, the `baz` example is just a variation on that.

Comment: I understand that they are values. The thing that I want to make clear is if they  are arguments that execute inside the function? and why they do after everything is done?

Comment: Callbacks never execute *by themselves*. The receiver needs to execute them at some point. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style

> I understand that arguments are just variables inside a function.
>   The thing that I want to make clear is if 
>   they are arguments that execute inside the function?

Hm, it's hard to say what you mean. Somehow this makes it seem that you think that the names are somehow the value cells.

Actually when you do this:

```
function f(y) {
    return y;
}

var x = 1;
f(x);
```

Then f(x) and the name y within f refer to the same value cell, the cell which has "1" in it (and no name in the cell - the name is not the value cell and the value cell can have MULTIPLE names referring to it).

What happens with continuation passing style is that instead of this:

```
function f(y, a) {
    return a * (y + 1);
}
f(y, a)
```

You can also do this:

```
function f(y, multiplyByA) {
    return multiplyByA(y + 1);
}
f(y, function(b) { return a * b; });
```

Note that how now you passed the function to use from the outside.
In that case, it is also possible that f, instead of calling multiplyByA immediately, remembers it somewhere and calls it later.

It can also, instead of calling it, give the (uncalled) function to someone else who will remember it somewhere and call it later, like this:

```
function f(y, multiplyByA) {
     window.setTimeout(20, multiplyByA);
}
f(y, function(b) { return a });
```

Note how setTimeout does NOT call multiplyByA immediately but just puts it away somewhere and returns to the caller.

After the time passed, it will call your function. This is no problem since the actual value cell is NOT limited to within the function or something - it is there for as long as it needs to be.

This is used every day in Javascript - for example let's say you want to do something after an answer to your XMLHttpRequest is there. Then you can create an XMLHttpRequest and set its onreadystatechange to your function. It will eventually be called.

Note that XMLHttpRequest will not block your application until the answer is there.
so instead of:

```
answer = XMLHttpRequest(...);
console.log(answer);
```

you do:

```
XMLHttpRequest(..., function(answer) {
  console.log(answer);
});
```

Notice how nothing is returned immediately, but rather your function will be remembered and it will be called back when something happens.

Note that in Javascript, the function has to be designed to use continuation passing style, you can't just use any function (note how the function f above changed (!) when introducing CPS).

"Don't call us, we call you"